# I Can't install PhpMyAdmin

Tags: apt, system-installation, apache2, mysql, phpmyadmin

Whenever I install phpMyAdmin, it gives the following error :-

```
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up phpmyadmin (4:4.5.4.1-2ubuntu2) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/phpmyadmin.postinst: 51: .: Can't open /usr/share/dbconfig-common/dpkg/postinst.mysql
dpkg: error processing package phpmyadmin (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 phpmyadmin
N: Ignoring file '50unattended-upgrades.ucf-dist' in directory '/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Now Please tell me what can I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This answer is a way to fix your problem but the origin of your problem is that you removed the `dpkg`'s file manually.

`sudo apt-get purge phpmyadmin`

`sudo touch /usr/share/dbconfig-common/dpkg/postinst.mysql`

(Do it for every file that is missing)

Then `sudo apt-get autoremove`

`sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin`

Comment: did not work for me, getting the same error.